# How to use multiple displays in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to add a title screen to my game in pygame using a title_screen function but whenever I call it it doesn't actually load the title screen, what am I doing wrong?

This is my code for the title screen function:

```
#started
started = False
#declaring surface
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')
def title_screen(canvas):


    canvas.fill(BLACK)
    #NOT WORKING
```

and this is how I'm calling it + how I'm calling the rest of the code for my game

```
while not started:
    title_screen(window)
    pygame.display.update()
    fps.tick(60)
init()
while True:
    draw(window)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            keydown(event)
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            keyup(event)
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    fps.tick(60)
```

Comment: Your title screen is a completely black screen, is that what you see?

Comment: No I see a completely white screen, that's the problem, the fill function isn't working for some reason, I have a feelings it's something to do with the display or surfaces

Comment: when I remove the title screen code it works just fine

Comment: Presumably you've declared BLACK as [0, 0, 0] or (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: Yes I've declared it as (0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

try to do pygame.init() before declaring window as an surface.